# Calculating proportion of a polygon covered by each raster category using R?

Tags: raster, r, polygon, terra

I am using R.

I have a polygon v that covers multiple raster cells in raster z.

How could I calculate what proportion of the polygon is covered by each category in the raster?

I read a solution on [Unexpected behaviour of extract function in the raster package](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/259733) which suggested rasterizing the polygon, polygonizing the raster, and then using terra::extract. This may work for the reproducible example here, but I'm looking for a solution that will scale to work with 2500 polygons and a raster with 100,000 rows and 100,000 columns.

I have assumed that the above solution would not work well with such a large dataset.

```
library(terra)

f <- system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra")
v <- vect(f)
v <- v[1,]
z <- rast(v, resolution=.09, names="test")
values(z) <- 1:ncell(z)
levels(z) <- 0:ncell(z)

plot(z)
plot(v, add = T)
```

[image: Map of raster z and polygon v]

Comment: Have you tried the `exactextractr` package? Its fast and gives you the area of partial grid overlaps. I'm using it on a 60,000x60,000 raster (with two layers) and its not too painful, your pain may vary depending on the complexity of your polygons and the power of your computer (but this is trivially parallelizable over polygons anyway).  Doesn't seem to yet work with `terra` so try `raster`?

Comment: See https://isciences.gitlab.io/exactextractr/articles/vig2_categorical.html for some examples. The vignette is written using `raster` but `terra` is supported and often much faster.

Comment: @dbaston Ah ha. `exact_extract` doesn't work with the *vector* polygon classes from `terra`, it can extract from the raster classes of `terra` but `y` has to be an `sf` or `sp` class polygonal object. I don't know why `terra` had to define yet another class of spatial data features but oh well..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for sending me in the right direction with exactextractr, @Spacedman. Here's the solution that I came up with:

```
library(terra)
library(exactextractr)
library(dplyr)
library(sf)


f <- system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra")
v <- st_read(f)
v <- v[1:2,]
z <- rast(vect(v), resolution=.09, names="test")
values(z) <- 1:ncell(z)
levels(z) <- 0:ncell(z)

plot(z)
plot(v, add = T)

#extract the area of each cell that is contained within each polygon
x <- exact_extract(z, v, coverage_area = TRUE)

#add polygon names that the results will be grouped by
names(x) <- v$NAME_2

#bind the list output into a df and calculate the proportion cover for each category
test <- bind_rows(x, .id = "region") %>%
  group_by(region, value) %>%
  summarize(total_area = sum(coverage_area)) %>%
  group_by(region) %>%
  mutate(proportion = total_area/sum(total_area))
```

Edit: With a big dataset, I was having memory issues with the code above. Here's a more memory efficient version:

```
### Summarizing function

sum_cover <- function(x){
  list(x %>%
    group_by(value) %>%
    summarize(total_area = sum(coverage_area)) %>%
    mutate(proportion = total_area/sum(total_area)))
  
}

#extract the area of each raster cell covered by the plot and summarize
x <- exact_extract(z, v, coverage_area = TRUE, summarize_df = TRUE, fun = sum_cover)


#add plot names to the elements of the output list
names(x) <- v$NAME_2

#merge the list elements into a df
test <- bind_rows(x, .id = "Plot_buffer")
```

Comment: *st_read* is from *sf* package. Please remember to load it.

Comment: Edited accordingly